# WPF: Listview set isSelected=True for the row name entered by user

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, listview

I am facing a problem when developing a listview control that is populated by dataset which I load from database. I can successful load it but now I want to do that when when the user key the words into the particular will set the selected = true by the words enter user. Something like following capture:
[image]

I will provide some code so that make the work more easily.
Just some concept for my design
XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication25.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <ListView Height="161" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,78,0,0" Name="listView1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="437" />
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,49,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="164,49,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Code-behind:

```
 protected void RefreshCategory()
        {

            SqlConnection conn;

            string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["house"].ConnectionString;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);

            conn.Open();
            String strSearch = "Select * from BudgetCategories WHERE CategoriesMonth='" + BudgetMonth + "' AND CategoriesYear='" + BudgetYear + "' ORDER BY CategoriesType DESC";
            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(strSearch, conn);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
            da.Fill(dt);
            CategoriesListView.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
        }
    }
```

Hope to receive response ... Thank you & have a nice day :)

Comment: I found it hard to understand this: `..but now I want to do that when when the user key the words into the particular will set the selected = true by the words enter user`

Comment: Sorry for the broken English...The thing that I wish to do is like this: I will provide an image for refer as a picture sometimes is more meaningful then thousands of words :)
http://i.stack.imgur.com/DjxoE.png

Comment: @A-MaxLee are you using MVVM for this project or just code-behind? If you're not using MVVM all you need is add an event handler on the `TextBox` for it's `TextChanged` event and iterate through the ListView items. You can then do your required checks and apply the IsSelected on matching items.

Comment: @A-MaxLee Check my answer. I assumed that there always be only one item matched the word user typed in textBox. And matching strategy is exact match, not contains/like. Let me know if you have different requirement..

Answer (score 1):

Here the idea, on TextBox's TextChanged event search for matching item in listView1.Items. If any item matched, set Selected Index of listView1 to index of that matched item.

Register method to handle TextChanged event:

```
<TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="38,49,0,0" 
                         Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" 
                         TextChanged="TextBox_TextChanged"/>
```

Search for matching item and set selected index to matched item if any:

```
private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var indexOfMatchedItem = -1;
    foreach (var item in listView1.Items)
    {
        if (item.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
        {
            indexOfMatchedItem = listView1.Items.IndexOf(item);
            break;
        }
    }
    if (indexOfMatchedItem != -1) 
    {
        listView1.SelectedItems.Clear();
        listView1.SelectedIndex = indexOfMatchedItem;
    }   
}
```

I am using List of string here as ListView's ItemsSource, you will need to do some adjustment to get it work with DataTable.

```
public Window()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var dt = new List<string>();
    dt.Add("one");
    dt.Add("two");
    dt.Add("three");
    listView1.ItemsSource = dt;
}
```

Another hint, since you are using DataTable you can change this line:

```
if (item.ToString() == textBox1.Text)
```

To this:

```
int columnIndex = 0; //set to index of the column displayed in ListView
if (((DataRowView)item).Row.Field<string>(columnIndex) == textBox1.Text)
```

Hope this get closer to your need.

Comment: I assumed that there always be only one item matched the word user typed in textBox. And matching strategy is exact match, not contains/like. Let me know if you have different requirement..

Comment: Thank you for answering me.
I got the concept but I still finding a way to implement as I'm using listview and databound with my database so that I still searching for the solution :(

Comment: @A-MaxLee Updated my answer to include a hint on how to adapt my code using DataTable. Let me know if you stuck somewhere else..

Answer (score 1):

Haha...Finally I come out a solution. The code is quite normal :|(In another words is noob). But can get it done then is superb :)

The solution is like this:

```
 protected void SelectID(){
            //Just a dummy value to store the matched item
            int indexOfMatchedItem=0;
            //This is the true essential part!!!
            //I intiatl as -1 as we are using index which start from -1 then increase ...1,2,3
            int index=-1;

            //Seen I'm using Listview DataContext bound with database.
            foreach (DataRow dtrCurrentRow in (((System.Data.DataView)CategoriesListView.ItemsSource)).Table.Rows)
            {
                //Retrieve the value frm the particula column:
                String value = dtrCurrentRow[0].ToString().TrimEnd();
                //MessageBox.Show("" + value);

                //Increase every time in counter a row:
                index++;
                //Match whether it is true or what:
                //Example: "C0001" equals "C0002":Will Not enter
                //Example: "C0002" equals "C0002":Will Enter
                if (value.Equals(Last_CID))
                {
                    //I can enter here already:

                         //The "Index" value with specific row index will be initial to the dummy "indexOfMatchedItem"                    
                         indexOfMatchedItem = index;
                         //MessageBox.Show("" + indexOfMatchedItem);
                         break;

                }
            }
            //When the dummpy position is equals to the current index postion in the list:Enter below code:
            //Example: 1 == 1
            if (indexOfMatchedItem == index)
            {
                CategoriesListView.SelectedItems.Clear();
                CategoriesListView.SelectedIndex = indexOfMatchedItem;
            }   

            }
```

Comment: Congrats, you managed to find out working solution for the problem/question. Consider to [upvote helpful answers and accept an answer that really work for you](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198551). Upvote means "thanks" here for those who give you hints to the solution. And accepting answer will make your question no more listed in 'Unanswered' category.

Comment: And in this case, this answer seems to be the working solution you can mark it accepted. But also, it looks inspired by my answer so I conclude that mine was useful, plz give mine at least upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution & I get the value but I don't why cannot get it fix but I know it is quite near to the answer already ... :)

Wish your all can help me on it...Thank you & have a nice day. I will post the code below ...

Code Behind:

```
protected void SelectID(){
    var indexOfMatchedItem = -1;

    //Seen I'm using Listview DataContext bound with database.
    foreach (DataRow dtrCurrentRow in (((System.Data.DataView)CategoriesListView.ItemsSource)).Table.Rows)
    {
        //Retrieve the each row the first column
        String value = dtrCurrentRow[0].ToString().TrimEnd();

        //Try & match:True or False
        if (value.Equals(Last_CID))
        {
            //I can enter here already:
            MessageBox.Show("HI");
                                      //This shoud be the index of the item which match the "value" string                      
                 indexOfMatchedItem = CategoriesListView.Items.IndexOf(value);
                 break;

        }
    }

    //I try to see whether the indexOfMatchedItem is pointing to the correct position in the list of the index.
    MessageBox.Show("" + indexOfMatchedItem);
    //But at the end it still pointing to -1
    //That's why I cannot enter the below code:

    if (indexOfMatchedItem != -1)
    {
        CategoriesListView.SelectedItems.Clear();
        CategoriesListView.SelectedIndex = indexOfMatchedItem;
    }   

    }
```

Got any solution for this??? Hope that receive respond .Thank you